# Detect local changes of JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have a website (game in JS). I would like to know if it's possible to detect if some client has edited and saved JavaScript file locally. My idea was to send the entire (or probably just part, it doesn't matter right now) .js file as POST parameter, so that PHP could compare it with .js file on server.

I've searched for local modifications, mutationobserver etc. but I haven't found the way.

Also, can JS file read itself?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to implement cheat detection. You can't control anything that happens on the client side. You must do your cheat detection on the server side.

Comment: If you worry someone will "borrow" your script, use this: https://javascriptobfuscator.com/

Comment: I'm not worried about borrowing, but about manipulating certain parameters to win the game.
I'm only trying to find the way to use content of .js file (make it read itself) as POST parameter